# Check already running github action self-hosted runner

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

How to check if any github action self-hosted runner is already running service on server machine?

I am trying to run self hosted runner on a server machine using run command I am getting below error :

```
PS C:\dev\actions-runner> ./run.cmd
        1 file(s) copied.

√ Connected to GitHub

A session for this runner already exists.
2022-11-16 12:37:55Z: Runner connect error: The actions runner TDCOGRLE1090685 already has an active session for owner TDCOGRLE1090685 .. Retrying until reconnected.
```

How to check all the runner sessions running on server machine?

Answer (score 2):

It can be directly checked in running services utility:

[image]